# ASP.NET Core Assign database values to a dropdown list for Edit action

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a controller with CRUD autogenerated and I am trying to fill values fetched from database to a dropdown.
My model class is like below

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ERPCustomerSupplier.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "User")]
        public string REQ_USERNAME { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Date")]
        public string REQ_DATE { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public string STATUS { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Customer Type")]
        public string CUSTOMER_TYPE { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Number")]
        public string CUSTOMER_NUMBER { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string ORGANIZATION_NAME { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public string COUNTRY { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        public string ADDRESS_LINE { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string CITY { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string STATE { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Operating Unit")]
        public string OPERATING_UNIT { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Currency")]
        public string CURRENCY { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Credit Limit")]
        public string CREDIT_LIMIT { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Credit Terms")]
        public string CREDIT_TERMS { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Bill To")]
        public string BILL_TO { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Ship To")]
        public string SHIP_TO { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Contact Person")]
        public string CT_PERSON { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Job Title")]
        public string CT_JOB_TITLE { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Department")]
        public string CT_DEPARTMENT { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Mobile")]
        public string CT_MOBILE { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string CT_EMAIL { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Phone")]
        public string CT_PHONE_NUMBER { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Ext")]
        public string CT_PHONE_EXT { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Fax")]
        public string CT_FAX_NUMBER { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Ext")]
        public string CT_FAX_EXT { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Assigned To")]
        public string ASSIGNEE_USERNAME { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Viewed Status")]
        public string VIEWED { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Territory")]
        public string TERRITORY_CODE { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Profile Class")]
        public string PROFILE_CLASS_ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Payment Terms")]
        public string PAYMENT_TERMS_NAME { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Payment Terms ID")]
        public string PAYMENT_TERMS_ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Profile Class")]
        public string PROFILE_CLASS_NAME { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Account Type")]
        public string ACCOUNT_TYPE { get; set; }


         public List<CurrencyList> currencyList { get; set; }

    }

    public class CurrencyList
    {
        public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }
        public string CurrencyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the Action Method as below

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            CustomerDataAccessLayer customer = new CustomerDataAccessLayer();
            Customer customer1 = new Customer {
                currencyList = customer.GetAllCurrencies()
            };
 
            ModelState.Clear();
  
            return View(customer.GetAllCustomers().Find(Customer => Customer.ID == id));
         }

        // POST: CustomerController/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

I populate the List using a Data Access layer

```
  public List<CurrencyList> GetAllCurrencies()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            List<CurrencyList> CurrenciesList = new List<CurrencyList>();

            string Orasql = @"Select CURRENCY_CODE, DESCRIPTION CURRENCY_NAME, PRECISION DECIMAL_POINTS  
                                from FND_CURRENCIES_VL where enabled_flag = 'Y'
                                ORDER BY 1";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(Orasql, conn);

            //OracleDataReader dr = new OracleDataReader();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                CurrenciesList.Add(
                    new CurrencyList
                    {
                        CurrencyCode=Convert.ToString(dr["CURRENCY_CODE"]),
                        CurrencyName=Convert.ToString(dr["CURRENCY_NAME"])
                    }
                    );
            }
               
            return CurrenciesList;

        }
```

Finally the view is like following:

```
@model ERPCustomerSupplier.Models.Customer


@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_SiteMaster.cshtml";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>Customer</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label asp-for="CURRENCY" class="control-label"></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <select asp-for="CURRENCY" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-items="Model.currencyList" />
                       <span asp-validation-for="CURRENCY" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </td>
```

and I get the error error "CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ERPCustomerSupplier.Models.CurrencyList>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

This is my 1st attempt with .Net Core & all helps are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means you must use **List SelectListItem** rather than List CurrencyList,

you should use SelectListItem instead to generate a dropdownlist,following is a demo (database is sqlserver, you can change to yours):

```
public class Customer
{
    [Display(Name = "ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Currency")]
    public string CURRENCY { get; set; }
    //....
    [NotMapped]   //add this
    public List<SelectListItem> currencyList { get; set; }  //change to SelectListItem
}
```

And I choose **ViewBag** to pass the selectListitem, it will be easier if you also want to

get the other properties in Customer Model:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //Fill data from database to currentList, and use ViewBag to pass.
        ViewBag.currencyList = _context.CurrencyLists.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.CurrencyCode, Text = c.CurrencyName }).ToList();            
        return View();
    }
```

View,and change the form too, your form will not show result:

```
<select asp-for="CURRENCY" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-items="@(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.currencyList" >
     <option>-Please select-</option>
</select>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: would you please share the code for filling data from the database?

Comment: @RajeshThampi In the demo ,`ViewBag.currencyList = _context.CurrencyLists.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.CurrencyCode, Text = c.CurrencyName }).ToList();` get data from database (The data is in CurrencyList Table, but you need to use your oracle way to get it) and put in Viewbag, then just call that ViewBag in View.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is my first attempt with .Net Core (without much exposure to MVC either). I am trying to populate this dropdown list from an EDIT action. All the examples I can see that the list is populated from Index action. How about populating from other actions like Create and Edit? My requirements would require the proceeding dropdown lists referring previous dropdown values.

Comment: Do you mean Cascade dropdownlist?check this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-simple-cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-core-mvc-with-new-tag-helpers/)

Comment: I've seen that example earlier and was reluctant to try it out as I cannot implement entity entity framework. I am going to work with Oracle EBS seeded tables, those don't have primary keys or well defined relationships. Anyway will checkout this sample. Thanks Tisa.

Comment: I managed to populate the dropdown list without using Viewbag, as recommended by Microsoft. Will post the code block as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Customer class modified from plain List item to List of SelectListItem

```
public List<SelectListItem> CurrencyList { get; set; }
```

List population modified with List object

```
 public List<SelectListItem> GetAllCurrencies()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            List<SelectListItem> CurrencyList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            string Orasql = @"Select CURRENCY_CODE, DESCRIPTION CURRENCY_NAME, PRECISION DECIMAL_POINTS  
                                from FND_CURRENCIES_VL where enabled_flag = 'Y'
                                ORDER BY 1";
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(Orasql, conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            conn.Open();
            da.Fill(dt);
            conn.Close();
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                CurrencyList.Add(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = dr["CURRENCY_NAME"].ToString(),
                    Value = dr["CURRENCY_CODE"].ToString()
                });
            }
            return CurrencyList;
        }
```

Modified Edit action as below:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            CustomerDataAccessLayer customerdataaccesslayer = new CustomerDataAccessLayer();
            Customer customer1 = customerdataaccesslayer.GetCustomerData(id);
            customer1.CurrencyList = customerDataAccessLayer.GetAllCurrencies();
            ModelState.Clear();
            //return View(customerdataaccesslayer.GetAllCustomers().Find(Customer => Customer.ID == id)); 
            return View(customer1); 
         }
```

Modified Edit.cshtml like following:

```
<td>
<label asp-for="CURRENCY" class="control-label"></label>
</td>
<td>
<select asp-for="CURRENCY" class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-items="Model.CurrencyList"></select>
<span asp-validation-for="CURRENCY" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Hope this helps few others.